# Issue Related to Scrollbar in MDI Form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a MDI From and a child form

Child form has height more than MDI child.. whenever child form opens in MDI form Scroll bar displays properly, but when i try to scroll it using mouse wheel, it heppens nothing?

how can i move down and up scroll using mouse wheel ?

Answer (score 3):

The mouse wheel notification message (WM_MOUSEWHEEL) is an unusual message, it "bubbles".  As long as no window processes it, the message is sent to the parent of the window.  Repeatedly until a window processes it or there's no more parent.

There's an unfortunate flaw in the Windows implementation of the MDI client window, the dark grey window you see on the MDI Parent window.  It is the one that displays the scrollbars but it isn't smart enough to process the mouse wheel notification.  Not sure why, but MDI is stone age old and existed long before mice got wheels.

Winforms is nice, it allows fixing flaws like this.  It can't be done by replacing the MDI client window, it is hard-baked.  What's required is sub-classing the window and catch the WM_MOUSEWHEEL message.  And add this missing functionality by making the window scroll with the WM_VSCROLL message.  That does take a bit of pinvoke magic, Winforms also doesn't make it easy to get a reference to the MDI client window.  Add a new class to your project and paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MdiScroller : NativeWindow {
    public static void Install(Form mdiParent) {
        if (!mdiParent.IsMdiContainer) throw new ArgumentException("Not an MDI application");
        if (!mdiParent.IsHandleCreated) throw new InvalidOperationException("Create me in the Load event please");
        foreach (Control ctl in mdiParent.Controls) {
            if (ctl is MdiClient) {
                var hooker = new MdiScroller();
                hooker.AssignHandle(ctl.Handle);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == WM_DESTROY) this.ReleaseHandle();
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL) {
            short delta = (short)((int)(long)m.WParam >> 16);
            SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)(delta < 0 ? SB_LINEUP : SB_LINEDOWN), IntPtr.Zero);
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    // PInvoke:
    private const int WM_DESTROY = 0x002;
    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a;
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const int SB_LINEDOWN = 0;
    private const int SB_LINEUP = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

}
```

In the MDI Parent form, implement the Load event handler or override OnLoad() to get this code activated.  Like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        MdiScroller.Install(this);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Or:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MdiScroller.Install(this);
    }
```

The code could be further improved by paying attention to the scroll amount (delta).  But this simple implementation already worked well on my machine, ymmv.

Answer (score 2):

Hans Passant's answer is great, but missing one point: If the parent form does not have a vertical scrollbar, the child forms disappear when scrolling...

The fix is simple -- you just have to check whether a vertical scrollbar is there; I copied Passant's `MdiScroller` class and added a few things:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MdiScroller : NativeWindow
{
    public static void Install(Form mdiParent)
    {
        if (!mdiParent.IsMdiContainer) throw new ArgumentException("Not an MDI application");
        if (!mdiParent.IsHandleCreated) throw new InvalidOperationException("Create me in the Load event please");
        foreach (Control ctl in mdiParent.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl is MdiClient)
            {
                var hooker = new MdiScroller();
                hooker.AssignHandle(ctl.Handle);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_DESTROY) this.ReleaseHandle();
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        short delta = (short)((int)(long)m.WParam >> 16);
        var scrollbars = GetVisibleScrollbars();

        // ** ADDED **
        if (scrollbars == ScrollBars.Horizontal || scrollbars == ScrollBars.None) { return;    }

        SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)(delta < 0 ? SB_LINEUP : SB_LINEDOWN), IntPtr.Zero);
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}

// ** ADDED **
private ScrollBars GetVisibleScrollbars()
{
    int wndStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
    bool hsVisible = (wndStyle & WS_HSCROLL) != 0;
    bool vsVisible = (wndStyle & WS_VSCROLL) != 0;

    if (hsVisible)
    {
        return vsVisible ? ScrollBars.Both : ScrollBars.Horizontal;
    }
    else
    {
        return vsVisible ? ScrollBars.Vertical : ScrollBars.None;
    }
}

// PInvoke:
private const int WM_DESTROY = 0x002;
private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a;
private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
private const int SB_LINEDOWN = 0;
private const int SB_LINEUP = 1;

// ** ADDED **
public const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
public const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;
public const int WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

// ** ADDED **
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

}

Comment: Upvoted! I spent a day trying to look for why my child forms disappear mysteriously. I forgot to read to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The way that a scroll mouse wheel works in Windows is that **the window with the *input focus* is the one that gets scrolled**.

That means that if your MDI *child* window has the focus, it will be the one receiving scroll messages. If it doesn't have a scrollbar, then it's just going to ignore those messages because it has nothing to scroll.

Compare that to if your MDI *parent* window has the focus. Then the parent will scroll, exposing the bottom of your MDI child window, just as if you moved the scrollbar attached to the parent window.

You can demonstrate this by clicking on the MDI parent window (like a blank space in the background that is not covered by the child window). When it receives the focus, your scroll wheel should cause it to scroll just like you expect.

Comment: @BoltClock: Ah, I've been extremely busy with school and work... And I haven't allowed myself to get involved (other than the minimum needed for research purposes!) lest I get sucked in and nothing productive done!

Comment: I tried focusing on MDI Form and also tried focusing even on mdi's scrollbar, yet it doesn't work ??