# Vertical Scroll Bar on MDI Parent Does Not Scroll Gradually

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mdi, mdiparent

I have written an MDI application in C# under VS2010.

When I drag the thumb on the vertical scroll bar, the window does not move until the thumb is released.

Research has turned-up some things, but none of the information I have found so far has worked.

Does someone have some guidance on this issue? I want the window to scroll as I drag the thumb.

Chuck

Comment: Try looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11601280/719186)

Comment: I implemented the solution in the article. The GREAT news is that the scroll wheel does work! That was a low priority on my list but none the less, on it.

However, when I drag the thumb, things do NOT move until I release it. Any further guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I want the window to scroll as I drag the thumb, the window does not
>   move until the thumb is released"

Set the Scroll Bar Property `ScrollTrack = True`

**Edit:**

Check the last example here:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/determine-scrolling-mdi-form-mdiclient-t1323005.html
its related to [detecting scrolls to repaint child forms to avoid flickering](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8553/MdiClient-Revisited#xx948448xx)

And please have a look what Hans Passant does here: [Issue Related to Scrollbar in MDI Form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599272/issue-related-to-scrollbar-in-mdi-form-in-c-sharp)

*psuedo code:*

```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            try
            {

                switch (m.Msg)
                {
                    //Scolling progress and Completion will be triggered
                    case WM_HSCROLL:

                    case WM_VSCROLL:
                          //this doesn't work 
                          //this.VerticalScroll.Value = x;

                          //I haven't tested this but it should definately work:
                          //http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setscrollpos
```

Comment: Jeremy, since I'm using the default scrollbar that appears in the MDI parent and not one that I have added myself, what is the name of the control that I reference in order to set the property?

Comment: Jeremy, thank-you. You provided alot of good info to digest and work with. I had not seen these articles in my digging around.

I had already overridden WndProc and know I have the same issue mentioned in the article with no scrolling event being generated.

Thanks again for your help. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Regarding the Hans Passant article, LarsTech had already pointed me to that. I implemented it. It made the mousewheel work but didn't help the scrolling issue.

It is amazing how messed-up MDI Client is in this area.